# Which is the maximal numbers of circles, such that each two circles are mutually tangent (in distinct points)?

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, circles

Given  [Descartes' "Kissing" Circles Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/descartes-theorem/), the answer seems to be 4.

But I wonder if there is a rigorous proof to that.

Comment: What is wrong with the proof shown in the link?

Comment: It's not clear for me that additional circles with the property in question can or cannot be added to the configuration of 4 circles from Descartes' theorem. There is nothing wrong with the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Given a finite set of circles in the plane, construct the simple undirected
[planar graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) whose vertices correspond
the the circle and two vertices are joined by
an edge if and only if the corresponding circles are tangent.

The case where the circles are all mutually
tangent corresponds to the complete graph with
the number of vertices equal to the number of
circles. In the case of four circles, the
complete graph with four vertices is planar.
By [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem)
the complete graph with more than four vertices is not planar. The Wikipedia article on the theorem states

> It states that a finite graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$ (the complete graph on five vertices) or of $K_{3,3}$ (complete bipartite graph on six vertices,